# Selenium cannot send keys to google map input selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to send keys to google maps to perform search, but Google Maps only accepts keys when the browser screen is in focus. I have tried input_box click, maximizing the window, action chain, and scrolling into view. The following is the code.

```py
import time
from undetected_chromedriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

"""Initialize and return the drivers"""
chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--incognito')
chrome_options.add_argument(
    "--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument("--mute-audio")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1400,1000")
chrome_options.add_argument(
    'user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36')
driver_installation = ChromeDriverManager().install()
service = Service(driver_installation)
service.service_args = chrome_options
driver = Chrome(service=service)
driver.get("https://maps.google.com")
time.sleep(3)
address = """Rett Syndrome Research Trust Inc
67 Under Cliff Rd
Trumbull, CT 6611"""
map_input = driver.find_element(By.ID, "searchboxinput")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(false);", map_input)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", map_input)
map_input.send_keys(address)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.click(map_input).send_keys(address).perform()
driver.quit()
```

None of the above works. Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `map_input.click()`?

Comment: @JohnGordon That also do not work

Comment: What exactly do you mean "does not work"?  Do you get an error?  Does the browser do something other than what you wanted?  If so, what?

Comment: I think the google is preventing input if the window is not focused once before input. There is no error though no input is done also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's got something to do with all the options you are setting up. The code below works fine for me.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://maps.google.com")
address = """Rett Syndrome Research Trust Inc
67 Under Cliff Rd
Trumbull, CT 6611"""
map_input = driver.find_element(By.ID, "searchboxinput")
map_input.send_keys(address)
```

Comment: Interesting. I will do a hit & trial to see which option is causing this

Comment: I looked into it. This is not because of chrome options instead undetected chromedrivers are causing this. Is there any solution to this because I want to use undetected chrome drivers